# wp_head(); isn't allowing all my HTML content to load in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a template for my WordPress website and for some reason it is not rendering all of my content.

Below is the code for it yet for some reason, not all my links in my site navigation are displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Wrestling News, Championship Belts and more | Europe's Home of Wrestling Belts</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
<link href="../css/body.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php wp_body_open(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'storefront_before_site' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'storefront_before_header' ); ?>

<div id="wrap">
<header class="bgBlack">
<div id="row">
<div class="column">
<a href="http://ehowb.com"><img id="logo" src="../images/header/logo.svg" alt="EhoWb logo" width="67" height="50"></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
<ul class="sm">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/497609223998966" target="_blank"><img src="../images/header/fb.svg" title="Join Our Facebook Group" alt="EhoWb Facebook Icon"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/EHOWB2018" target="_blank"><img src="../images/header/tw.svg" title="Follow Our Twitter" alt="EhoWb Twitter Icon"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/ehowb1/" target="_blank"><img src="../images/header/insta.svg" title="Follow Our Instagram" alt="EhoWb Instagram Icon"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCASURe6nPXbjzRYzAzU-O8w" target="_blank"><img src="../images/header/yt.svg" title="Subscribe To Our YouTube Channel" alt="EhoWb YouTube Icon"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div id="nav">
<a id="close" class="txtWhite" onclick="navClose()">&times;</a>
<div id="overlay-nav" class="show">
<li><a href="../about" title="Find out more about us">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="../blog" title="Check out the official blog">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="../contact" title="Get in touch with us">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="../shop" title="Visit our online store">SHOP</a></li>
</div>
</div>
<a id="open" class="txtWhite showmenu" onclick="navOpen()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<a href="#" onclick="fntop()" id="top" title="Back to Top">&#8593;</a>
<div id="banner" class="bgHome txtGrey">
<h1>Welcome to Europe's Home of Wrestling Belts</h1>
</div>

        <?php
        do_action( 'storefront_header' );
        ?>

    <?php
    do_action( 'storefront_before_content' );
    ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="col-full">

        <?php
        do_action( 'storefront_content_top' );
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this please? I am having real trouble and could do with some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enqueued your custom CSS and js file in function.php?
please check here to add CSS and js file [Enqueue Script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [Enqueue Style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: thank you so much worked an absolute treat much appreciated!